# Restore Partiton only on change

Tags: restore, hashing

I have wrote a script that restores a partition from a previous made `dd` dump. Basically it calls this line:

```
dd if=stored_image.img of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M
```

The restore for this takes about 5 Minutes (20GB of Data) and it would be great to only restore the image if no changes where made.
Of course i can check now the whole partition with a hash and compare it with the previous one, but the hash generation is only as fast as i can read from the device, so a `md5sum /dev/sdb1` also needs about 5 minutes to calculate...

The question is now: is there any way of detecting changes on the disk very fast? (like under half a minute) There is no need to be 100% sure, but at least 90% accuracy should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound like a "heavy" solution but I would recommend mdadm for this. mdadm has a feature called "write-intend bitmaps". To keep it simple you can think of it like an array of ones and zeros, where every number represents a given amount of data on your disk. The amount of data it represents depends on the size of your bitmap.

So lets say you have 20GB of data and you have a 20 bit bitmap, every bit represents one GB of data. Everytime a write is made to your mdadm RAID the corresponding bit of the one GB section is switched to one.

What I would suggest now is that you create a "fake RAID 1" with a write intend bitmap, and every now and then you want to "sync" your image you just "connect" the image to the mdadm raid. mdadm will then make sure that all sections where the write intend bitmap is 1 and says "this section is dirty", it will automatically sync the data to your image.

I've create a little bash script as example for you:

```
# Create 2 images (loop1 could later be your /dev/sdb1)
fallocate -l 1G loop1.img
fallocate -l 1G loop2.img

# Create loop deveices for mdadm
losetup /dev/loop1 loop1.img   #### you don't need this step for /dev/sdb1 of course

# Create a RAID 1 with only loop1 or sdb1, replace /dev/md/<bitmap> with a suiteable name
mdadm --create -l 1 -n 2 --bitmap=internal --bitmap-chunk=128 /dev/md/bitmap /dev/loop1  missing
```

so calling "cat /proc/mdstat" should return something like:

```
md121 : active raid1 loop1[0]
  1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
  bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 128KB chunk
```

The [U_] menas the first device (loop1) is "U"p, and the second is missing (_).
With --bitmap-chunk= you can determin how big the chunks of data per bit are. Smaller values give better rebuild speed/granularity, lager values give you less write-speed impact for keeping the bitmap in sync.

If you want to sync your image, just create a loop device from it and add it to the raid:

```
losetup /dev/loop2 loop2.img
mdadm --add /dev/md/bitmap /dev/loop2
```

/proc/mdstat will say its recovering your image, which the first time is a full copy:

```
md121 : active raid1 loop2[2] loop1[0]
      1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      [===>.................]  recovery = 18.7% (196608/1047552) finish=0.1min speed=98304K/sec
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 128KB chunk
```

You can either leave you image in the RAID1 all the time to keep it in sync, or you can remove it after the sync is finsihed. If you want to script it you may find it usefull to check /sys/block/md121/md/sync_action for "idle". This means the recovery is complete.

Now you can remove the image by:

```
mdadm --fail /dev/md/bitmap /dev/loop2
mdadm --remove /dev/md/bitmap /dev/loop2
```

After changing a few bytes:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/md/bitmap bs=4k count=1k seek=1000
```

You see that there are dirty bits on the bitmap:

```
md121 : active raid1 loop1[0]
  1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
  bitmap: **1/4 pages** [4KB], 128KB chunk
```

Re-adding the image will recovery the image and only sync the dirty sections is no time...

```
mdadm --re-add /dev/md/bitmap /dev/loop2
sync
```

Output should be:

```
md121 : active raid1 loop2[2] loop1[0]
  1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
  bitmap: **0/4 pages** [0KB], 128KB chunk
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately i cannot use mdadm there. but for other cases this seems to be really great!
i should had mentioned, that i need this to restore some windows test systems, where the system partition is restored in every case and some data partition may or may not have changed.

Comment: So if you are not able to use some "software layer" in between, because you use a different OS on that partition later on, the only think that I could come up with is generating a list of files with "last modified" timestamps, store it on the same filesystem and then later generate it again and diff it. This would only check the "metadata" on the filesystem, not the whole data.

Comment: You could generate a list with something like 'find -printf "%t %p\n"|sort'

Comment: yes, but of course that list generation is also limited by the disk's read speed... also the timestamps could be misleading, because files are only accessed. I think a proper solution would be to have mdadm on windows ;)

Comment: Limited by read speed? So a complete list of a huge partition with 90k files takes about 12MB. Modern disks have read speeds about > 100MB/s. This would take 100ms to read...I don't think read speed would be an issue here. But you can also do 'find -printf "%t %p\n"|sort|gzip'. My file list then takes 2MB. Accessed files are not changed. So I don't see a problem. Every write updates the modified timestamp. So this should be sufficient.